# Declare a global scope variable const in c++

Tags: c++, c, scope, global

In C or C++, is it possible to declare a const with global scope, but the definition is set inside a function?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: I'm programming in an asynchronous environment and the variable picks up the wrong definition if I don't set it in one particular spot.

Comment: That isn't particularly clear.  If you have `const int x = 3;` at a global scope, it will be `3` wherever/whenever you reference it.  Can you show a concrete example of the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Which is also why I need a const, if it gets set more than once Bad Thynges happen

Comment: But it shouldn't get set more than once.

Comment: http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/60231/20/camera/CameraWrapper.cpp

Comment: What's that link meant to show? **What is the problem you're trying to solve?**

Comment: You can write `const int x = foo();`, however this is fragile code because it is not specific which order `foo()` is called, relative to other global variable initialization.

Comment: @JonathanWakely what do you mean what is the link trying to show? I was asked to provide the actual code I was trying to use.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm attempting to find a calling pid for an Android camera wrapper, the problem is finding a consistent place to read the pid that's outside the mutex and doesn't unnecessarily read it again and again (which can lead to it getting set to null or the system process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about doing something like ([live sample](http://ideone.com/lse9EM))

```
const int& MyConstValue(int x) {
    static const int myConstValue = x;
    return myConstValue;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << MyConstValue(5) << std::endl; // This is the 1st call and "wins"
    std::cout << MyConstValue(8) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
5
5
```

At least for [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) this is even guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: This would be placed in global scope? and wouldn't get initialized until it was called at least once?

Comment: @user3353209 _'This would be placed in global scope? ...'_ Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

No, that is impossible. The declaration must be in the same scope as the definition. Otherwise, it's not the same name.